# How to add a sprite on top of another sprite in Flame Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flame

The app has a background image using `SpriteComponent` and I try to add another Tile image on top of the background image. Why the `crate.png` image doesn't appear on top?

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(GameWidget(
    game: CGame(),
  ));
}

class CGame extends FlameGame {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    SpriteComponent crate = SpriteComponent()
      ..sprite = await loadSprite('crate.png')
      ..size = Vector2(100, 100)
      ..position = Vector2(250, 300);

    add(crate);
    add(Background());   //<== comment this line to see the loaded crate.png
    add(Crate());

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}

class Background extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('background.png');
    size = gameRef.size;

    return super.onLoad();
  }

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    super.render(canvas);
  }
}

class Crate extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('crate.png');
    size = Vector2(100, 100);
    position = Vector2(200, 200);

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your crate will be behind the background because it loads faster and therefore is added to the component tree faster, to solve this you'll have to set the priority of the crate:

```dart
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(GameWidget(
    game: CGame(),
  ));
}

class CGame extends FlameGame {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    add(Background());
    add(Crate());

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}

class Background extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('background.png');
    size = gameRef.size;

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}

class Crate extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef {
  Crate() : super(priority: 1); // <-- This is what changed

  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('crate.png');
    size = Vector2(100, 100);
    position = Vector2(200, 200);

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

The default priority of components are 0 and the higher the priority is the "closer" to you the component will be, like a higher z-index. So here when we set the crate's priority to 1 it will always appear in front of the background which still has the default priority 0.

And a side note: you don't have to call the `render` method manually in `Background`, it is done automatically.

Comment: You don't have to create a subclass of `SpriteComponent` to set the priority -- it can be set with `..priority = 1` along with the other properties like `size`, `sprite` and `position`.

Comment: Very true, but then the component won't be responsible for its own asset loading.
So it depends a bit on what your needs are and since the person asking the question already had it in a component I went with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by adding

```
 SpriteComponent spriteCompo = SpriteComponent()
      ..sprite = await loadSprite('background.png')
      ..size = size;

    add(spriteCompo);
```

to the `CGame` class, but there is a question why it is not working when calling a class Background?

**Working snippet:**

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(GameWidget(
    game: CGame(),
  ));
}

class CGame extends FlameGame {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {

    SpriteComponent spriteCompo = SpriteComponent()
      ..sprite = await loadSprite('background.png')
      ..size = size;

    add(spriteCompo);

    // add(Background());
    add(Crate());

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}

class Background extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('background.png');
    size = gameRef.size;

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}

class Crate extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    sprite = await Sprite.load('crate.png');
    size = Vector2(100, 100);
    position = Vector2(200, 200);

    return super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

Comment: This works because you have loaded the background image before you add it to the game, it is better to handle it with priority.